# stream.PipeTo() finishes node process

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, stream, backend

I've been learning about WebStreams. I wrote a simple code that uses ReadableStream and WriteableStream.

But when I want to show a message on console after stream.pipeTo(), it doesn't works. What's the problem?

The code is the next:

```
const myStream = new ReadableStream({
  start: (controller) => {
    controller.enqueue("message")
  }
})

let fullContent = ""
const writable = new WritableStream({
  write: (chunk) => {
    fullContent += chunk
    console.log("writing: " + chunk)
  }
})


async function leerStream () {
  try {
    await myStream.pipeTo(writable)
    console.log("AFTER PIPE MESSAGE")
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

leerStream()
```

And it shows in console the next (after pipe message isn't showing)

`writing: message`

I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: The `preventClose` option of [`PipeTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/pipeTo#options) suggests the promise returned by the method is only fulfilled or rejected when the piped stream closes. If true and  `myStream` is never closed, then the  `await` operand in `leerStream`  keeps waiting indefinitely.

Comment: It worked! I will read about that. Thanks!